# what is the most elegant way to convert between JSON hash format, and actual hash format? in ruby?

Tags: ruby, json

This is the hash I'm faced with (though the original I'm sending just has sections point to an array):

```
{"sections" => {
 "0" => {},
 "1" => {}
}}
```

It should be

```
{"sections" => [
 {},
 {}
]}
```

Ideally, I'd like to extend the Hash class... but my brain is a smidge fried at the moment.

thanks.

this is my current progress:

```
 def un_json
    self.each do |k, v|
      if v.is_a?(Hash) and k.is_a?(Number)
        # iterate over k's objects, then remove k from self
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: this is as far as I've gotten, but I'm not sure how to remove the entire hash once I've iterated through it.   def un_json
    self.each do |k, v|
      if v.is_a?(Hash) and k.is_a?(Number)
        
      end
    end
  end

Comment: Post this code to the question. Also, specify why exactly you don't like your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array = []
hash['sections'].each do |i,val|
  array[i.to_i] = val
end
hash['sections'] = array
```

Comment: this should help me right a recursive extension of Hash. thanks

Answer (score 2):

with ruby standart library json.

```
require 'json'

j = '{"sections": {
       "0": {},
       "1": {}
     }}'

p JSON.parse(j)

# {"sections"=>{"0"=>{}, "1"=>{}}}
```

Comment: I get this error: TypeError (can't convert HashWithIndifferentAccess into String):
  json (1.6.5) lib/json/common.rb:148:in `initialize'
  json (1.6.5) lib/json/common.rb:148:in `new'
  json (1.6.5) lib/json/common.rb:148:in `parse

The first code snipped is what ruby is auto-converting the json to =(

Comment: your example is correct. however, it's not what I'm asking for. =\

Comment: Have a look at the answer I just posted... it does what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one quick and dirty way:

```
h = {"sections" => {
                     "0" => {},
                     "1" => {}
                   }}
result={}
h.each do |k,v|
  result[k]=v.values
end

result.to_json
```

returns:

```
"{\"sections\":[{},{}]}"
```

Comment: That only works if the `"sections"` keys are in sorted order.